# Can I refresh the thumbnails programmatically?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I would like to be able to refresh the thumbnail cache programmatically, not sure where to hook it, but at present any design changes mean re-uploading loads of images!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to look at the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails by Viper007Bond](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Basically, this is how to do it:

```
function regenerateThumbnails() {

    $images = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'" );

    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        $id = $image->ID;
        $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $id );

        if ( false === $fullsizepath || !file_exists($fullsizepath) )
            return;

        if ( wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $fullsizepath ) ) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Note: This function is not very scalable. It will loop through all the images and regenerate thumbnails one by one, which may consume a large amount of memory. So, you may want to enhance it.

Comment: how might we scale it?

Comment: @MildFuzz: The plugin now does this in an Ajax loop, so only one image is resized per request. You just leave the browser window open while it processes each image in sequence. If you do it in one request (as the plugin used to do), you run into memory and time limits.

Comment: what would be good is if we could write a function that could hook into the loading of the attachment, and if the right one is not present, create it.

Comment: *@Mild Fuzz*: By *"loading of the attachment"*, do you mean when the file is requested by the browser? If so, you'd end up putting a significant performance drain on the server because currently Apache serves images, WordPress never handles them. You could try hook the 404 template and try to figure out what to generate from there but there might but unexpected incompatibilities. Wish I had time to fiddle with it but sadly I don't right now. Maybe you could tell us a bit more about your situation and use-case? Why is the standard approach not working for you?

Comment: @*Mild Fuzz* - You could also run code similar to the code *@sorich87* provided on a pseudo-cron task: http://bit.ly/wp-pseudo-cron